# Access files written into /tmp with aws sam local

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I am working on a project using AWS SAM local. I am invoking a function with
`sam local invoke` which successfully executes the function. The lambda function writes an image file into `/tmp/image.png` when the function is invoked. This writing operation happens in the environment of SAM local, the `/tmp` folder belongs to its docker environment.

Is there a way for me to access the files written into the `/tmp` folder while developing locally?

Answer (score 1):

This apparently has been answered on their github:
[Link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/773)

You create a /c/tmp directory and set the TMPDIR=/c/tmp environment variable while invoking.

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML doc</title></head><body>Content<body></html>' | TMPDIR=/c/tmp  sam local invoke "HtmlToPdfFunction"
```